# Efficient deterministic algorithm for quadratic residues

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

In Elliptic Cryptography, one may need the calculation of the quadratic residue over a finite field to [generate a random point on the curve](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68603/18298).

In simple terms, given the equation of the curve as short Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^3 + x + 1$ over a finite field $F$, select a random element $x \overset{r}{\leftarrow} F$ and check that $y$ is a quadratic residue. After that one can use square root algorithms to determine the $y$ and $-y$ values and randomly select one of them.

SageMath has a function for this [random_element()](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.html) not detailed the algorithm behind in the docs.

When I've searched for algorithms for calculating the quadratic residue and the Wikipedia states;

> Tonelli (in 1891) and Cipolla found efficient algorithms that work for all prime moduli. Both algorithms require finding a quadratic nonresidue modulo n, and there is no efficient deterministic algorithm known for doing that.

These works are from 1996. Is there any advancement in this area?

Comment: You are looking for finding the square root in a finite field. The quadratic reciprocity will tell you if it is a quadratic residue. A little googling brings you to this newer source : https://cr.yp.to/papers/sqroot.pdf (Though I haven't read it.)

Comment: E.random_point?? in Sage gives you the source code of its implementation. It uses lift_x which just uses sqrt

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thanks. Yes, checking that QC will tell us to reject the sample or not, then we need square roots. An efficient square root may remove the QR check, which would imply a fast algorithm for QR, too. Lifting, I'll check that.

Comment: I just mention it because the title of the question seems to be a different question than the one in the body of the text: Determination of all quadratic residues is simply squaring all elements from 1 to (p-1)/2.

Comment: One standard algorithm for this is [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm#Generalizations), which is (as you found) deterministic up to finding a quadratic nonresidue. In practice (e.g. application to elliptic cryptography, as is your motivation), finding a quadratic nonresidue is NEVER an issue, in view that checking random elements can find one in expected two tries.

Comment: Jeremy Booher claims in this exposition from 2012 that 1) computing square roots is equivalent to finding QNRs, 2) no deterministic polynomial-time algorithm for the latter is known unconditionally, 3) conditional on the GRH, the smallest QNR is $O((\log p)^2)$, so assuming GRH, testing the first $O((\log p)^2)$ residues is a deterministic polynomial-time algorithm: https://www.math.canterbury.ac.nz/~j.booher/expos/sqr_qnr.pdf